# Redshift nested json extraction

Tags: json, amazon-redshift

I have a table with two columns, one column named `user`, one json column named `js` that looks like this:

```
{"1":{"partner_id":54,"provider_id":13},

"2":{"partner_id":56,"provider_id":8},

"3":{"partner_id":2719,"provider_id":274}}
```

I want to select all 'provider_id' in one column/row.So it should look like this:

```
user| provider_ids
0001| 13,8,274
0002| 21,36,57,12
```

How can I do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Your provided json format is not so easy to work with.

Crated table for test purposes:

```
create table json_test as
select '0001' as usr, '{"1":{"partner_id":54,"provider_id":13},
"2":{"partner_id":56,"provider_id":8},
"3":{"partner_id":2719,"provider_id":274}}'
as json_text
union all
select '0002' as usr, '{"1":{"partner_id":54,"provider_id":21},
"2":{"partner_id":56,"provider_id":36},
"2":{"partner_id":56,"provider_id":57},
"3":{"partner_id":2719,"provider_id":12}}'
as json_text;
```

Query to return results:

```
with NS AS (
  select 1 as n union all
  select 2 union all
  select 3 union all
  select 4 union all
  select 5 union all
  select 6 union all
  select 7 union all
  select 8 union all
  select 9 union all
  select 10
)
select usr,
 listagg(trim(TRIM(split_part(SPLIT_PART(js.json_text, '},', NS.n),'"provider_id":',2)),'}'),',') within group(order by null) AS t
from NS
join json_test js ON true and NS.n <= REGEXP_COUNT(js.json_text, '\\},') + 1
group by usr;
```

Notes:

1) do not name column "user" as it is reserved keyword

2) add as many dummy rows in NS subquery as there is maximum of json provider records

3) Yes, I know, this isn't very readable SQL :D